# jQuery parent() in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to access the div tag in the following HTML code:

```
<table>
    <div class="rowBound">
      <tr onclick="expandLastResultDetails(this);">
        <td class="c1">56835-14513</td>
        ...
      </tr>
      <tr class="rowDetails">
        <td colspan="0">
        <div style="background-color: #0F9;"> expandable
         </div></td>
      </tr>
    </div>
</table>
```

But jQuery commands just give me a TBODY instead of my DIV ..

This is what I was doing in another case:

```
function expandNavContent(navEntryTitle) {
    var content = $(navEntryTitle).parent().children('.navContent');
    $(content).slideToggle('slow', function () {
        // Animation complete.
    });
}
```

What I want:
rowDetails should be animated with slideToggle if someone clicks on the tr

If I use this code:

```
function expandLastResultDetails(tableEntry) {
    var content =$(tableEntry).parent().children('.rowDetails');
    $(content).slideToggle('slow', function () {
        // Animation complete.
    });
}
```

It toggles ALL rows but it should just toggle ONE row so I nested them into a division, maybe that was wrong

Comment: Your markup is invalid. `<tr>` elements are part of table, not a block.

Comment: Sorry this is just a part of code let me edit..

Comment: Maybe try animating `tbody` (if you want to animate all `tr` elements at once) instead on wrapping them in that div. I don't think it is correct to nest a `div` in a table definition like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('tr.rowDetails').find('div');
```

But, your Markup is not valid. `tr` is element of `table`, not for `div`.

To get the outer parent `div`:

```
$('tr.rowDetails').closest('div');
```

#### After edit

```
function expandLastResultDetails(tableEntry) {
    var content =$(tableEntry).next('.rowDetails'); // will point to next tr
    $(content).slideToggle('slow', function () {
        // Animation complete.
    });
}
```

Comment: It should be dynamic so I want to give jQuery the "this" reference

Comment: Cool that is working! Thanks very much.. any ideas why the slideToggle does not slide?

Comment: Okay I got it:
var content =$(tableEntry).next('.rowDetailsRow').children('td').children('div'); 

Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 2):

Try `$('.rowDetails').closest('div.rowBound');`

It will bubble from the current element (outwards) until it find a div element.

Hope it helps

Comment: It should be dynamic so I want to give jQuery the "this" reference

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You mentioned that you want to use "this". What are you referring to? The `tr` that was clicked?

Answer (score 1):

What command did you try? You could have used this:

```
$(".rowDetails tr td div");
```

And moreover, there cannot be a `<tr>` inside a `<div>`!

Comment: The OP wants to get the outer div, not the inner

Comment: @ZoltanToth first of all the HTML itself is wrong... Anyways, which `div` is the OP talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Since your markup is invalid the browser will propably insert the tbody and table for you (look at the markup in FireBug/Dev tools). Something like `$(".rowDetails").parent().parent().parent()` could work (in some browsers) but I'd recommend fixing the markup instead